# Why can't Gerrit load the secure.config file created by the init process?

Tags: java, gerrit

I am attempting to run Gerrit in a Docker container along with Postgres and Apache following the instructions in https://medium.com/@joonasvenlinen/gerrit-with-http-authentication-1e7ae5fb7359. I am able to start up postgres and apache without issues, but Gerrit fails with the following error:

```
gerrit_1    | [2020-04-13 19:45:22,460] [main] ERROR com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon : Unable to start daemon
gerrit_1    | com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:
gerrit_1    |
gerrit_1    | 1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load secure.config
gerrit_1    |   at com.google.gerrit.server.securestore.DefaultSecureStore.<init>(DefaultSecureStore.java:41)
gerrit_1    |   at com.google.gerrit.server.securestore.DefaultSecureStore.class(DefaultSecureStore.java:41)
gerrit_1    |   while locating com.google.gerrit.server.securestore.DefaultSecureStore
gerrit_1    |   while locating com.google.gerrit.server.securestore.SecureStoreProvider
gerrit_1    |   at com.google.gerrit.server.config.GerritServerConfigModule.configure(GerritServerConfigModule.java:80)
gerrit_1    |   while locating com.google.gerrit.server.securestore.SecureStore
gerrit_1    |     for the 2nd parameter of com.google.gerrit.server.config.GerritServerConfigProvider.<init>(GerritServerConfigProvider.java:55)
gerrit_1    |   at com.google.gerrit.server.config.GerritServerConfigProvider.class(GerritServerConfigProvider.java:43)
gerrit_1    |   while locating com.google.gerrit.server.config.GerritServerConfigProvider
gerrit_1    |   while locating org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Config annotated with @com.google.gerrit.server.config.GerritServerConfig()
gerrit_1    |     for the 1st parameter of com.google.gerrit.server.config.RepositoryConfig.<init>(RepositoryConfig.java:44)
gerrit_1    |   at com.google.gerrit.server.config.RepositoryConfig.class(RepositoryConfig.java:39)
gerrit_1    |   while locating com.google.gerrit.server.config.RepositoryConfig
gerrit_1    |     for the 1st parameter of com.google.gerrit.server.git.GitRepositoryManagerModule.<init>(GitRepositoryManagerModule.java:26)
gerrit_1    |   while locating com.google.gerrit.server.git.GitRepositoryManagerModule
```

My gerrit.config file looks like this:

```
[gerrit]
        basePath = git
        canonicalWebUrl = http://<server-name>:8080/
[database]
        type = postgresql
        hostname = localhost
        database = reviewdb
        username = gerrit2
[index]
        type = LUCENE
[auth]
        type = HTTP
        logoutUrl = http://aa:aa@<server-name>:8080/logout
        httpHeader =
[sendemail]
        smtpServer = localhost
        smtpUser = gerrit2
[plugins]
        allowRemoteAdmin = true
[container]
        javaOptions = "-Dflogger.backend_factory=com.google.common.flogger.backend.log4j.Log4jBackendFactory#getInstance"
        javaOptions = "-Dflogger.logging_context=com.google.gerrit.server.logging.LoggingContext#getInstance"
        user = gerrit2
        javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.el7_7.x86_64/jre
        javaOptions = -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
        javaOptions = -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
        javaOptions = -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
        javaOptions = -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
[receive]
        enableSignedPush = false
[httpd]
        listenUrl = http://*:8080/
[cache]
        directory = cache
[sshd]
        listenAddress = *:29418
[user]
        name = gerrit2
        email = gerrit2@whoi.edu
```

Update: changing the permissions on the secure.config file - which seemed to be the recommended action, causes a different error that requires that the gerrit.war file be rebuilt. Doing that results in the secure.config error, so it seems I'm looping between two different exceptions.

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!